# osx media player which can skip forward/backward 5/10secs

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, media-player

I am using OSX 10.6 and just wondering if there is any media player that can skip forward/backward 5/10secs like what Winamp can do in Windows platform?

Currently I am using Quicktime player, and it can only fastforward 2x,4x,8x etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get [Movist](http://code.google.com/p/movist/) and go to preferences, there you can define size of steps which will be skipped using `←/→`, `⌥ + ←/→` and `⌘ + ←/→`.

Answer (score 2):

[VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) can do that. Type `Alt + right/left` or `Ctrl + right/left`.

Comment: You can also re-bind it to non-stupid keys, such as plain unmodified arrows.

Comment: If you have a trackpad, you can also use your fingers: 2 fingers left or right to skip backward/forward.